# Java Android error : "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, toast

Im writing a java app passing data (the users name) from the first activity to another activity where it is displayed. The user then enters an email address to be passed back to the first activity, im trying to display the returned email data as a toast but keep getting the error "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (Context, String, String, int)"

i have used toasts in my other applications and never had this problem before so im obviously missing something. Im new to java android programming so any advice  will be helpful

below is the section of code dealing with the returned data and attempting to display it as a toast

can anyone suggest why i am getting this error and how to fix it?

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (data.hasExtra("Choice")) {

         Toast.makeText(ExplicitOne.this, "Choice sent back:", tvDataRet,      
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this.

Concatenate the string then pass in the second argument. This is static method of Toast class having three parameter.

```
Toast.makeText(ExplicitOne.this, "Choice sent back:" +  tvDataRet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: yes it has sold that problem error 
`
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence DataRet = "your choice:" + (CharSequence) tvDataRet;
       
Toast.makeText(context, DataRet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return;
`
however the app now closes when the toast should be returned, i will post the solution when i work it out